# What happens on the moon launch?

Tags: adventure-capitalist

So I'm very close to launching to the moon, but I know I won't get it before i have to go offline, so I'm wondering if it's worth spending angels speeding up the launch.

What happens when the launch happens?  Do you have to wait extra time, or can you start building a set a business that makes the money / angels back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you have a great supply angels, then you might as well get the launch over with. And once the timer is done you can start your new adventure.

**HOWEVER:** Do not be confused, this is a brand new world. **None** of the angels itself transfer. The boosts that you can purchase for gold **do not transfer**.

This is a brand new start to a brand new slower world. So get ready to do it again.

Comment: So nothing carries over?  I kind of hoped that it would let you transfer between Mega and Earth cash and that maybe MC would end up being used to purchase a business.  Oh well, I think I'll just leave it.  Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Ya sadly that doesn't happen. There also isn't a lot of ways to speed up your current production. Try it out. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth spending only your safe angels (less than 1%), otherwise it's better to wait and earn more angels. I've purchased all possible speed ups for the launch which affected my total of angels very little (e.g. trillion of angels, having billion). Spending more than 10% of your angels on the launch isn't worth it, it's better to wait.